# Calculate sum and average treating blank values with specific values based on other column condition without adding helper column

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to calculate the sum and average in Google Spreadsheet of a range based on conditions from another column, but treat blanks with a specified value. It can be accomplished using a helper column, but I would like to do it without it. Here is the sample data:

[image: sample]

I would like to sum values in column `B` based on value on Column `A`, but replacing blanks values with the value specified on `E2` and `E3` respectivelly.

Here is a sample in google sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Cv9YxFMHuGq2biNNCdGsjU8cAD_OwCPTR4YCPLc2r34/edit?usp=sharing

I was trying to use the following formulas for the sum of team A but I am not getting the expected result:

```
=sumif(A2:A,"A", if(B2:B<>"",B2:B,E2)) returns 6 instead of 19
=sum(if(A2:A="A",if(B2:B<>"", B2:B, E2),)) return 27 instead of 19
```

I cannot use a combintation of `sumif` and `arrayformula` like this because it expects a range in the third input argument:

```
=sumif(A2:A,"A", ARRAYFORMULA(if(B2:B<>"", B2:B,E2)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't going to jump in on this one, since it's after midnight and I didn't feel I had the energy to both write *and* explain such a formula. But I see that you yourself have helped others on this forum. So I'll soldier through for you.

Delete everything from columns G:I (i.e., leave those columns entirely blank); and I suggest removing all of the formatting that you currently have in place in those columns, since it won't make sense after what I propose below.

Place the following formula in G1:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(FILTER({A2:A,IF(B2:B="",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A&"*",D:E,2,FALSE),0),B2:B)},A2:A<>""),"Select Col1, SUM(Col2), AVG(Col2) GROUP BY Col1 LABEL Col1 'Team', SUM(Col2) 'Sum', AVG(Col2) 'Average'"))`

This one formula will generate all headers, team names and results for all teams' sums and averages.

The virtual array between the curly brackets pairs every element of A2:A with the results of the `IF` function. That `IF` function checks to see if B2:B is blank. If so, a `VLOOKUP` with wildcard is performed to find the Col-A team name at the start of any value in Col D and, if found, returns the corresponding filler value from Col E. (If not found, `IFERROR` returns 0 as the filler value. It's important to have a numerical value because of the way `QUERY` works.)

`FILTER` filters in all of the above results only for those rows where A2:A contains a non-null value.

`QUERY` then pulls the team names, sums and averages; the `LABEL` portion of the `QUERY` assigns your desired column headers to the results.

This formula is not restricted to only two teams. You can add as many teams as you like in A:B and assign as many filler values as necessary in D:E.

It's important to note, however, that the formula relies on the FULL team name found in A:A being found at the beginning of the Col-D values. So if your team name is "Bears," just make sure the corresponding entry in Col-D starts with "Bears" as well (e.g., "Bears blanks" or even just "Bears").

You'll need to format the entire Col H as whole numbers and the entire Col I as *0.00* to match the results you shown in your sample.

**ADDENDUM** (after further comments from OP):

It seems that what you're saying is that the D:E values in your sample spreadsheet were something you wanted included within the formula itself and that you did not intend for them to be used as a reference list. I think your post's reference to "without a helper column" may have been your attempt to say this; but it was not clear, as with or without that D:E list as a live reference range, the main formula may have relied on its own helper column *in addition* to that list.

If you want a formula that *contains* the list:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(FILTER({A2:A,IF(B2:B="",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A,{"A",2;"B",4},2,FALSE),0),B2:B)},A2:A<>""),"Select Col1, SUM(Col2), AVG(Col2) GROUP BY Col1 LABEL Col1 'Team', SUM(Col2) 'Sum', AVG(Col2) 'Average'"))`

To add further blank-values, just keep adding to this section...

`{"A",2;"B",4}`

... being sure to follow the pattern of team-comma-value-semi for all but the last entry which will not need the closing semi.

Comment: Thanks for your response and your consideration of me. The solution works perfectly. The only consideration I have is that it relies on the values on column D, where it finds the team names and not only on the values of column E. For two teams we can replace the filter portion with this: `FILTER({A2:A,IF(B2:B="",IF(A2:A="A",E2,E3),B2:B)},A2:A<>"")` but if we have more teams we need to add additional `IF`conditions. Your solution is really more generic.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying, David. The formula I wrote needs no modification to add teams. It "relies on the values in column D" to find the Col-E value you want assigned to blanks for each team, yes. But if you don't want a value added for blanks for a team, you just wouldn't add them to D:E. You also have weird characters added at the start of the QUERY function (`K7º `) which is producing an error.

Comment: Please see image sequence added to my post. The formula does not change. But you can see that as soon as I add a new team and points value, it appears in the QUERY, whether I add a blank-value for that new team or not. If I then add a blank points cell for that team, it simply gets a value of zero. You can then see that if I add team "C" to the D:E list with a blank-value, that is taken into account. Again, the formula is not modified during any of these changes, but the output is correct.

Comment: Thanks, @ErikTyle, as I mentioned the solution works perfectly, actually I added a second tab in my sample and tested it. My comment is that your solution forces you to have an additional column with the team names, instead of indicating the team names in a formula, for example, `sumif` formula doesn't require having the team condition in a specific column, you just need to specify in the formula. That is my point. The proposed `FILTER` on my comment doesn't need it but is not generic, so I guess this is the price to pay in order to have a generic solution. Thanks for your solution!

Comment: See my **ADDENDUM** to the post for another update.

Comment: Thanks, @ErikTyler for the Addendum this is really an elegant solution. I accepted your response over the one provided by Ian Kenney because yours is more generic, but both are valid ones for my initial question.

Comment: Great. Thanks for reporting back.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `sumifs` and `countifs`

to add up the non-blanks

```
=sumifs(B2:B10,A2:A10,"A")
```

to add up the blanks (and multiply by the default value)

```
=countifs(A2:A10,"A",B2:B10,"")*E2
```

all together

```
=sumifs(B2:B10,A2:A10,"A")+countifs(A2:A10,"A",B2:B10,"")*E2
```

Average (use countifs to work out how many items):

```
=(sumifs(B2:B10,A2:A10,"A")+countifs(A2:A10,"A",B2:B10,"")*E2)/countifs(A2:A10,"A")
```

Comment: Thanks, @IanKenney how this approach would work for calculating the average?

Comment: thanks @IanKenney it works I added to may sample file your solution into Sheet1